# NotificationCompat cannot be resolved / Notification in Android 2.3 and up

Tags: android, notifications

I'm looking for a way to use NotificationCompat. Every time I istance it eclipse say "NotificationCompat cannot be resolved". I have android support library (and I added it in Java class path).
What am I doing wrong? 
Is there an other way for android 2.3+?
Thank you

Comment: Nothing, because it say that cannot be resolved. I try "import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;" but eclipse say: "The import android.support cannot be resolved".. I have to chage android support library with another?

Comment: Are you using old SDK? Did you copy the support library to libs folder before adding to class path?

Comment: I'm using Eclipse ADT v22.0.1-685705, yes, I put library in libs folder.

Comment: Now I found another way.. but it's deprecated: Notification notification = new Notification(icon, tickerText, when);